# What is the best option to manage the tracking of a user's activity?

Tags: node.js, typescript, apache-kafka, backend

my project has many backend systems and an application that interacts with them. I have to make a user activity tracking system like:

user: 123
action: create-something
data: ...
...

I'm thinking of using kafka because it streams messages and other systems can subscribe to user activity.

the problem is this: all users can see their own activity logs, but in kafka I can't do a "query", so I have two ideas:

First option:
have topic "user activity" and topic "user activity-{id}" per user, so I can write posts in both topics, all records in "user activity" and a copy of them in topic of the user. This sounds easy, but what if I have 10 million users? is it scalable?

Second option
just the "user activity" topic and when you get a message send it to redis with the user id as well

Another option?

really, i dont tried nothing, only testing how kafka works

Comment: It's not clear what the actual **problem** is. Kafka is... quite scalable (and queryable; not sure what you mean by not being able to query it), but the ROI if you're not already in the ecosystem may be low. Seems like you just need a place to throw audit logs from multiple sources w/ an index on the user ID.

Comment: In any case: the question is too broad, opinion-based, and non-specific--off-topic on SO :)

Comment: This is a very broad question and without more information about the current stack, there are an infinite number of solutions. Instead of introducing Kafka to the equation, would it be possible to solve this with systems already in use? ie- using trigger functions which write to the activity log when data is changed. Then subscribe to the activity log with websockets. Updating the UI would be another matter.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.